In memoriam: Barry N. Malzberg
Barry N. Malzberg passed away on Friday, Dec. 20th, at the age of 85.  He was a prolific writer of short stories (hundreds in total, and over a hundred just in the first half of the 1970s alone) as well as an essayist and an editor.
His often dark and psychologically-oriented (especially later) fiction was not always to my taste, but many of his stories stick in the mind, like the often-collected novella "Final War."
SFWA has posted an in memoriam article for him, and he also has a Wikipedia page.
